# helper function that binds on hooks returns http error 500

Tags: php, codeigniter

So first I have this helper 'test.php' (application/helpers)

```
if ( ! function_exists('testdemo')) { // check if function exist, if not the create
    function testdemo($id=false){
        $CI =& get_instance(); // get CI instance

        echo $CI->session->userdata('user_info');
        exit;
    }
}
```

and then bind it to the hook so it will run every time a controller is called

(application/config/hooks.php)

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => '',
        'function' => 'testdemo',
        'filename' => 'test.php',
        'filepath' => 'helpers',
        'params'   => false
);
```

and then I get this http error

[image]

any ideas, help please?

Comment: Local or remote testing environment?

Comment: local environment

Comment: in `index.php` set env to `development` to enable error reporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `load` method is not available in `pre_controller`, hence you cannot access libraries (such as session).

In `pre_controller`:

> All base classes, routing, and security checks have been done.

You can use `post_controller`.